# SQL Syntax Error with update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I'm trying to set up a way for users to set settings, i'm saving the settings in a json format in the databse. When I try to update the user though I get this syntax error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''settings' = '{\"background-color\":\"050505\"}'
>   WHERE `ID` = '2'' at line 1 in
>   C:...\htdocs\app\model\model.database.php on line 29

Here is the code that I have.

```
public function setColor(){
    $modUser = $this->model('user');
    $modInput = $this->model('input');
    $modViewData = $this->model('viewData');
    $modUser->setSetting("background-color",str_replace('#', "", $modInput->returnPost("color")));
    $this->view('profile/view.profile', $modViewData->getData());
}
//in User model
public function setSetting($name, $value){
    $settings = $this->getSetting();
    $settings[$name] = $value;
    $settings = json_encode($settings);
    $this->update("settings", $settings);
}
public function update($field, $value){
    $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET :field = :value WHERE `ID` = :id";
    $params = [":field" => $field, ":value" => $value, ":id" => $this->_data->ID];
    $database = $this->model('database');
    $database->query($sql,$params);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot a parameterize table and column names.  You need to insert those directly into the query string.  One method is:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET $field = :value WHERE `ID` = :id";
```

Comment: Is safe from sql injection? I would guess so unless the field is being passed in by the user which it shouldn't be.

Comment: Been stuck on that for a while and that worked! Thanks tons.